# Is there a possibility to validate POSTMAN request fields if they mandatory or not

Tags: api, postman

I want to ask if there is an ability to run postman request a lot of times by one click (without creating a lot of duplicates) and at the each run validate if one of the JSON attribute is mandatory or not. Please provide information on how to do it.

Example Scenario:

1. I run "CREATE ORDER" put request (it has three mandatory fields - sourceSystem, customer, buyerOrderNumber)
2. Postman runs "CREATE ORDER" the first time and validates getting the 400 Bad Request error when sending "CREATE ORDER" without sourceSystem field
3. Postman runs "CREATE ORDER" the second time and validates getting the 400 Bad Request error when sending "CREATE ORDER" without customer field
4. Postman runs "CREATE ORDER" the third time and validates getting the 400 Bad Request error when sending "CREATE ORDER" without buyerOrderNumber field

[image]

Comment: Can you share an example of what the request body looks like please?

Comment: @DannyDainton yes, sure.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, just paste the code in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Tests or assertions to the `Pre-request Scripts`, to check that certain keys are part of the request body:

```
pm.test("Check request properties", () => {
    let requestData = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)
    pm.expect(requestData).to.have.keys(['sourceSystem', 'customer', 'buyerOrderNumber'])
})
```

In your scenario's, you can just remove the key for the array that you want to see the correct response code/message - You could double this up by having a Test for the 400 code in the `Tests` tab.